# Building specific Navigation animation with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to build such an effect with Flutter by navigate from one page to another?

[image]

Do you have an idea to build an effect like that? I would post code examples, but I really have no idea how to do anything like this...

Answer (score 1):

I think the navigations between those pages are the [Hero Animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations).

As for another transition, you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition).

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Hero` Widget to achieve this.

In the first screen wrap your image with `Hero` widget and provide it with a tag.
In the second screen wrap your image with `Hero` widget and provide it with the same tag.

```dart
Hero(
  tag: 'firstImage'
  child: Image.asset('images/1.png'),
)
```

You can watch the Hero widget video in the Flutter widget of week https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw&feature=emb_logo.

To read more about the hero widget, you can checkout https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations.